# Can't remove burg theme packages

Tags: package-management

Today after trying to install and remove BURG and few themes I faced an issue. Now I can't install or remove anything.

Here is the output (unfortunately partly in Finnish, I couldn't change language since it also seems to depend on package listings:

```
lassi@lassi-ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get autoremove
Luetaan pakettiluetteloita... Valmis
Muodostetaan riippuvuussuhteiden puu       
Luetaan tilatietoja... Valmis       
Seuraavat paketit POISTETAAN:
  burg-theme-fortune burg-theme-gnome burg-theme-picchio
0 päivitetty, 0 uutta asennusta, 3 poistettavaa ja 0 päivittämätöntä.
3 ei asennettu kokonaan tai poistettiin.
Toiminnon jälkeen vapautuu 7 180 k t levytilaa.
Haluatko jatkaa [K/e]? k
(Luetaan tietokantaa... 166462 files and directories currently installed.)
Poistetaan pakettia burg-theme-fortune...
sudo: update-burg: command not found
dpkg: virhe käsiteltäessä burg-theme-fortune (--remove):
 aliprosessi installed post-removal script palautti virhetilakoodin 1
Poistetaan pakettia burg-theme-gnome...
sudo: update-burg: command not found
dpkg: virhe käsiteltäessä burg-theme-gnome (--remove):
 aliprosessi installed post-removal script palautti virhetilakoodin 1
Poistetaan pakettia burg-theme-picchio...
sudo: update-burg: command not found
dpkg: virhe käsiteltäessä burg-theme-picchio (--remove):
 aliprosessi installed post-removal script palautti virhetilakoodin 1
Käsittelyssä tapahtui liian monta virhettä:
 burg-theme-fortune
 burg-theme-gnome
 burg-theme-picchio
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Basically what seems to happen is this:

It creates the package lists, then tries to remove packet burg-theme-fortune.
This fails as update-burg command was not found. Then dpkg reports an error while processing the packet.

Same goes with all 3 packages.

In the end it claims that there were too many errors, and packages stay installed.

I also tried installing burg as it tries to run command update-burg, but appears that it tries to delete these packages always when I try to install or remove or do anything with apt.

Any ideas how I could solve this issue?

Edit: Here is the output of apt-get install burg (tried installing again to get English output)

```
    lassi@lassi-ubuntu:~$ LC_ALL=C sudo apt-get install burg
[sudo] password for lassi: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
burg is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/6169 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
(Reading database ... 167497 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace burg-theme-fortune 0.5.0-1 (using .../burg-theme-fortune_0.5.0-1_all.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement burg-theme-fortune ...
Generating burg.cfg ...
/usr/sbin/burg-probe: error: cannot stat `/boot/burg/locale'.
No path or device is specified.
Try `/usr/sbin/burg-probe --help' for more information.
dpkg: warning: subprocess old post-removal script returned error exit status 1
dpkg - trying script from the new package instead ...
Generating burg.cfg ...
/usr/sbin/burg-probe: error: cannot stat `/boot/burg/locale'.
No path or device is specified.
Try `/usr/sbin/burg-probe --help' for more information.
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/burg-theme-fortune_0.5.0-1_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Generating burg.cfg ...
/usr/sbin/burg-probe: error: cannot stat `/boot/burg/locale'.
No path or device is specified.
Try `/usr/sbin/burg-probe --help' for more information.
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess new post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Preparing to replace burg-theme-gnome 0.5.0-1 (using .../burg-theme-gnome_0.5.0-1_all.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement burg-theme-gnome ...
Generating burg.cfg ...
/usr/sbin/burg-probe: error: cannot stat `/boot/burg/locale'.
No path or device is specified.
Try `/usr/sbin/burg-probe --help' for more information.
dpkg: warning: subprocess old post-removal script returned error exit status 1
dpkg - trying script from the new package instead ...
Generating burg.cfg ...
/usr/sbin/burg-probe: error: cannot stat `/boot/burg/locale'.
No path or device is specified.
Try `/usr/sbin/burg-probe --help' for more information.
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/burg-theme-gnome_0.5.0-1_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Generating burg.cfg ...
/usr/sbin/burg-probe: error: cannot stat `/boot/burg/locale'.
No path or device is specified.
Try `/usr/sbin/burg-probe --help' for more information.
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess new post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Preparing to replace burg-theme-picchio 0.5.0-1 (using .../burg-theme-picchio_0.5.0-1_all.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement burg-theme-picchio ...
Generating burg.cfg ...
/usr/sbin/burg-probe: error: cannot stat `/boot/burg/locale'.
No path or device is specified.
Try `/usr/sbin/burg-probe --help' for more information.
dpkg: warning: subprocess old post-removal script returned error exit status 1
dpkg - trying script from the new package instead ...
Generating burg.cfg ...
/usr/sbin/burg-probe: error: cannot stat `/boot/burg/locale'.
No path or device is specified.
Try `/usr/sbin/burg-probe --help' for more information.
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/burg-theme-picchio_0.5.0-1_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Generating burg.cfg ...
/usr/sbin/burg-probe: error: cannot stat `/boot/burg/locale'.
No path or device is specified.
Try `/usr/sbin/burg-probe --help' for more information.
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess new post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/burg-theme-fortune_0.5.0-1_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/burg-theme-gnome_0.5.0-1_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/burg-theme-picchio_0.5.0-1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
lassi@lassi-ubuntu:~$
```

Comment: What happens when you re-install burg, remove the theme(s) and then remove burg again?

Comment: I tried force installing BURG and what got mainly errors. I added the output of installing BURG to the main post.

Comment: Also, it would help, if you try to get English output preprending the commands with `LC_ALL=C`, e.g.,, `LC_ALL=C sudo apt-get install burg`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a long shot, but you can try:

```
sudo mkdir /boot/burg
sudo touch /boot/burg/locale
```

Then try again to reinstall burg:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall burg burg-theme-fortune burg-theme-gnome burg-theme-picchio
```

Once everything is installed, remove the themes first, and finally Burg.